# In a function in won't compile but outside it will

Tags: list, scala, type-mismatch

```
def combinations(list: List[(Char, Int)]) : List[List[(Char,Int)]]= {
  val t = List.range(0, 1)
  list match {
    case List() => List()
    case (c,i) :: xs => val res = for {
      o <- List.range(1, i + 1)
      } yield List((c, o)) :: combinations(xs)


  List()


  }
```

}

I have the following function which won't compile if I try to return res instead of List(). It's a type mismatch of `List(List(List[(Char,Int)]]]` However this code:

```
 List(('a',10)) :: combinations(List())
```

compiles perfectly and as expected. Why is it that inside the function it won't compile? Isn't it the exact same thing? How could I tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

Your for-comprehension yields an element of type `List[List[(Char,Int)]]`.
For-comprehensions will generate lists of the elements they're yielding, so in this case that will be a `List[List[List[(Char,Int)]]]`.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but I think it'll be something like this:

```
def combinations(list: List[(Char, Int)]) : List[List[(Char,Int)]]= {
  val t = List.range(0, 1)
  list match {
    case Nil => List()
    case (c,i) :: xs => 
      (for {
        o <- List.range(1, i + 1)
      } yield (c, o)) :: combinations(xs)
  }
}
```

The for-comprehension generates a `List[(Char, Int)]` which is added at the head of the list generated by your combinations method.

Comment: What you posted does compile but it misses the point of the algorithm. What you are doing is concatenating the combinations of the first element to the possibilities of the second. What I tried to do, was to combine every single possibility of one element to every possibility of the second one